# Disable "most relevant items" recommendations in Google Inbox search results

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

When I search Google Inbox for certain keywords, the top 3-5 results will be shown as "most relevant" based on some sort of algorithm. Usually the mail I need is not among them, so this is mostly a nuisance. All of these mails are then repeated below in proper order as you can see in this (downsized) screenshot.

[image] ([click here for large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8POp.png))

Is there a way to disable these top results?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

The following Adblock filter works for me, at least in the [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom):

```
inbox.google.com##DIV.DsPmj[jsinstance="0;0"]
```

To add it, visit the [Adblock settings](http://chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/options/index.html), locate "Manually edit your filters", click "Edit", and add a new line with the above. Don't forget to save there and then reload Google Inbox.

Be aware this will make stuff slower, and that it may have side effects (in particular, it may hide things you don't want hidden) -- although so far, I am not missing anything obvious. "Snoozed" and "Done" still have the top ("Today") sections, and quickly going through the other categories, I do not notice anything unusual, either.